# Run a saved bigquery query from Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

We frequently use Google Apps script to run BigQuery queries and put them into a Google Sheet. However, the workflow is annoying:

1. Run the query in BigQuery until you get it right.
2. Copy/paste to a text editor to put in the newline slashes
3. Run it in apps script and hope it works
4. Go back to BigQuery and repeat 1-3 if something doesn't work.

Is there some way to just save a query using BigQuery's save function, and then call that specific query from a script?

Answer (score 3):

Its a workaround...

try saving as a view, and execute a simple

```
Select * from MyView
```

Comment: What is the difference in view and table? Suppose I have a BigQuery query that shows lastday value (not hardcoded but results depend on the current day). Does the view get automatically updated each day?

Comment: Could this solve issue here? I.e. to save the query results as a View in BigQuery instead of manually inserting the code to be executed in BigQuery?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038821/how-to-run-a-saved-big-query-script-from-file-in-google-app-script

Answer (score 0):

At my [blog](https://bitvectors.blogspot.com), I wrote an [article](http://bitvectors.blogspot.com/2014/08/page1.html) that shows how to front-end a BigQuery project with a Google Apps Script application "owned" by a Google Drive spreadsheet. The article describes a simple example application available at my GitHub repository. This sample application

1) builds a web page that directly queries BigQuery

2) shows the result set on the web page

3) mirrors the result set on the spreadsheet

The sample solution has two small files - that's it. You probably have a BigQuery project more complicated than the one featured in the [article](http://bitvectors.blogspot.com/2014/08/page1.html), but the main idea of the article / sample should extend to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery Team definitely has some secret sauce here as they actually have this functionality in their Native BigQuery UI – you can save and then reuse it from within that UI

As of using saved query programmatically I can recommend this route:

1. run your query anyhow and get respective jobid
2. do jobs/get (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get) for that specific jobid within your script to get configuration.query.query that consists of query text
3. then just use it the way you need
4. if to properly wrap it – can be quite useful :0)

Answer (score -1):

If you query data in BigQuery, build reports and visualize results on a regular basis, you will enjoy our [free Add-on for Google Sheets](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/owox-bi-bigquery-reports/fepofngogkjnejgcbdmmkddnpeojbbin).

It will make your workflow easier.

Benefits:

1. Analysts and developers can create shared SQL-queries with
   pre-defined variables,
2. Queries are saved for future use,
3. Variables allow modifying the result without editing SQL-syntax,
4. Visualize, manipulate and share data enjoying the benefits of Google
   Sheets,
5. Everything works 100% in the Google Cloud and absolutely
   safe: data from Google BigQuery is directly inserted to Google
   Sheets.

Any suggestions and comments are welcome.

Comment: This type of answer tends to not do so well on StackOverflow (or StackExchange in general) since it can quickly turn into somebody trying to peddle their product, which isn't in the spirit of the website. However, I just tried the Add-On and it does appear to do exactly what the asker was looking for (and, in turn, what I was looking for)